# http://www.domain.com/user/abc to http://www.abc.com/

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns

I'm currently developing a website where one can make their own small site / shop and sell their homemade foods and beverages. Any profit will go to a charity organisation.

I want to give the users the possibility to use a real domain name instead of http://www.domain.com/user/username.

So basicly my question is: what is the best way to display the contents of http://www.domain.com/user/username on http://www.newdomainname.com?

Comment: It depends on what web server you're using, but simple server config is generally all that is needed depending on how your application is built.  Some applications need to be explicitly configured to handle cases like this.

Comment: connect to the host and database of first domain in the second domain and get the data from db. same DB for two domains

Comment: @Brad I don't have a webserver yet, only shared hosting at this moment. When the project is finished i'll look into what I need. Can you tell me more about what server configuration you are talking about? Or give me some keywords so I can Google it myself?

Comment: A quick way to make the site available is to create a redirect from newdomainname.com to domain.com/user/username. Problem is that the user will know he's being redirected (the URL changes).
Are you able to use mod_rewrite and .htaccess files on your webhost?

Comment: @Rotharius I have a variable which holds the 'site name'. So when I change this variable from http://www.domain.com/user/username to http://www.newdomainname.com all the links etc. should be working. Yes mod_rewrite and .htaccess should be available when I have a webhost (currently developing it locally). It would be nice if the user wouldn't know that the URL is changing.

Comment: @guy1997 You can simply point each virtual host config at a specific directory.  If you have a more advanced application, don't set up virtual hosts at all and configure your application to detect what domain is being used (based on the Host request header) and output the correct site.